# Should I go for a power bank that has 5v output and 12 volt output

Tags: power-supply, usb-power

I have found this power bank ( http://www.amazon.in/Penibel-PT-10-10000mAh-Technology-smartphone/dp/B01FY58PLG?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=2c2001f7-f9b7-4db1-9b28-9403e817f186#immersive-view_1473098833799 ) and it uses some smartfit technology to detect how much input is required for device plugged into USB of power bank . This power bank has 2 USB output one I want plug into raspberry pi and other I want to plug into net gear wifi router that supports port forwarding ( since I want to self host ).

What is your opinion about going for this device ? 
I am only sceptical about smart fit technology but on the other hand it outputs 5v / 2.4 A which I guess is perfect for my pi 3!

Comment: *"on the other hand it outputs 5v / 2.4 A which I guess is perfect for my pi 3!"* -> That's what you think, but [see here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/54242/5538).  YMMV.  It's sold as something for recharging other batteries so regardless of how many mA it can put out this does not mean that it will deal with rapidly fluctuating current draws even when they are much less than the maximum.  I believe all those "built-in safeguards...against over-current, overcharging and overheating" may make it less than perfect for anything except recharging.

Comment: In that case what should I go with to overcome fluctuations ? I was also looking for compact design and simultaneously charging could have helped me keeping up with fluctuations

Comment: Read the whole answer linked above and have a look at the two example devices (one suggested by me, one in a comment underneath) that are intended for this kind of use.   This is just an observation and not to say it can't work, so if you could use that power bank anyway it may be worth the gamble.  Otherwise I would focus on something which is explicitly sold as a form of UPS with a long life battery in it.

Comment: So the power boost 1000 can be put after power bank that in turn correct voltage to pi 3 ! I do not want to rely on batteries .

Comment: I'm not sure if you could simply attach that to a power bank because of the additional circuitry in the power bank.  It's intended to be connected straight to actual batteries.  That said, most of the cost of a power bank is I think in the batteries and the big one I have is easy to take apart (likely most of them are, presuming you don't necessarily want to put them back together), so you could always buy one and take the batteries out.  Just make sure they're not more than 3.7V.

Comment: Great I guess I have power bank that's not working but I assume batteries are fine

Comment: This is off-topic according to [this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help center article. In the end, you still decide what you need and what you will purchase, so I think you'll be better off doing your own research.