# Is it ok to power rpi3 + high current usb device with battery pack and y cable?

Tags: power, usb-power

I want to supply a rpi3 + a high-current (up to 450ma) usb device portably. Is it ok to get a battery pack with two usb outputs, attach the rpi3 to it, attach the data end of the y cable to the rpi3, and the power end to the battery pack?

Or, is there a better way to do this?

I ask because I've read that Y-cables are not really part of the USB standard.

As a side question, am I correct to assume that it would *not* be okay to power the rpi3 through a wall plug, and a usb device with a y-cable and battery pack, since the two devices would not share a common ground?

Comment: Your question is unclear - what does "power the rpi3 through a wall plug, and a usb device with a y-cable and battery pack" mean? Why not just power your USB device from the Pi3 USB ports?

Comment: Because the pi cannot supply that much current through a usb port, if i understand.

Comment: USB can supply 1.2A (given an adequate PSU) See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)

Comment: I.... I did not know that, thank you. I must've been reading the wrong things. That solves everything. If you make an answer, I'll mark it as chosen.

Comment: If by "batter pack" you mean a power bank sold for recharging mobile devices, be prepared for disappointment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/54242/5538

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a better way to do this

Just power your USB device from the Pi3 USB ports which can supply 1.2A (given an adequate PSU) See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)